# How long does geoserver store the cookie it generates from authentication via j_spring_security_check?

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I have a website which connects to a geoserver, it fetches sessions from geoserver via j_spring_security_check. How long is the cookie given by geoserver valid and can I edit its expiration?